# Input character validation on keypressed in WICKET (no AJAX)?

Tags: javascript, ajax, wicket

What I mean is:
How can I prevent the user from typing invalid characters in a form input in Wicket? I don't want an Ajax behavior, due that I don't think making Ajax calls to the server is the right approach for something that doesn't require server interaction, but I do want to use the validators I have already defined for the input.

Is there any way to accomplish that?

Comment: You would have to implement a javascript validator if you don't want ajax and want to validate on keypressed.

Comment: I would also recommend to go back to previous questions you have asked and mark answers as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for would need to be done in some Javascript that is contributed to the page by a Wicket **Behavior**.

In Wicket 1.5 all the standard validators now extend **Behavior** and thus can contribute to the page at render-time.

The intent of this is to allow validators to be customised to add javascript for things such as client-side validation.

That said, there is no out-of-the-box feature for this, in addition if you're using Wicket 1.4 or earlier you will need to create a custom validator that implements IBehavior as validators and behaviors are separate mechanisms prior to 1.5.